# Is there an 'Extract to...' context menu option for the Archive Manager application in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, menu, archive, extract, file-roller

I was wondering if there was an easy way to add an 'Extract to...' option in the context menu for the Archive Manager in Nautilus?

'Extract here' is fine a lot of the time but I'm often working with a lot of archives whose content is just 'loose' within the archive and I want it extracted in to a sub-folder for better organisation. Having to manually create the folder first becomes really tedious when dealing with lots of archives.

I was also hoping that it would be possible for this (or another) function to automatically create a folder with the same name as the archive and extract the contents there. Again for ease of management and so I don't have to keep typing out long complicated archive names by hand.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Having to manually create the folder first becomes really tedious when dealing with lots of archives.

This is not required. Try creating a zip file with 2 files without a folder. When you extract it with "Extract here" it will create the folder automatically.

If the folder exists, it will create a new folder, *MyArchiveFilename (2)*.

If there's only one file in the archive, only then it is extracted in the current directory, without creating a subfolder.

Comment: ...oh so it does! (embarrassed now) Thank you so much for this! I can't believe I'd never realised this before. I'd always assumed it wouldn't so just opened the archive manager and created the folder manually. You've just saved my fingers (and time) much effort. Big thanks though to @Mitch too as his tip will surely come in handy!

Comment: No need to be embarassed, we could all make the same mistake. Cheers, enjoy Ubuntu and its community. :)

Comment: anyway to change the default behavior so that it extracts a single file to a folder?

Comment: If however archive contains 2 folders, they will be extracted as are, in the current directory :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can.  Install the Nautilus Actions Configuration utility.  To do so

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Or

[image: Install via the software center]

For information on how to use it, you can [take a look at this.](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/using-nautilus-actions-extend-file-manager-functionality-linux/) It shows you an example on how to use it