# Archive manager that extracts into new folder named after archive

Tags: archive, file-roller

file-roller, xarchive, 7zip (with a tedious workaround) have the following workflow:

Extract the files in the folder containing myarchive without creating a folder myarchive and extracting into there.

Peazip, Winrar have the option to extract archive into a new folder named with the archive name.

Peazip is out of the question becuase it does not support implicit tar.gz archives.

1. Is there an archive manager that support gz,tar,bz,rar and zip that integrates with the pcmanfm context menu that can extract into a new folder as specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu a right-mouse-click (contexmenu) on a .bz .gz .7z .bz2 etc always unpacks to a folder in my experience. The program used is....fileroller.

Also take a look at this: [Is there an 'Extract to...' context menu option for the Archive Manager application in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151656/is-there-an-extract-to-context-menu-option-for-the-archive-manager-applicat?rq=1)

If all else fails:  `file-roller -h  filename`
the -h option forces the creation of a directory in which the files are unpacked. The name of the directory is the same as the archive name minus the filename extention. see: `man file-roller`

Comment: I've looked at that thread before posting but it did not answer the question posed in this one. Presumably you mean "Extract here" in the context menu? That extracts folders directly into the folder of that archive's location which is the abomination that I am trying to get around.

Comment: Strange...if I do "Extract here", it first creates a subfolder with the name of the archive (without the filename extention).  Very strange....unless it is because I use nautilus instead of pcmanfm. I will try with my Lubuntu version...I'll come back to you.

Comment: I am running ubuntu 12.04. I'm going to try upgrading file-roller. I tested zip and tar.gz thinking that perhaps it was behaving as specified on tar.gz but that is not the case. It is behaving the same way with nautilus.

Comment: I found something: running file-roller with the -h option actually does what you want. see:  man file-roller

Comment: Thanks! What is the actual behavior on your ubuntu and which version? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1419614 It is specified here that the behavior of nautilus is as requested in this thread, however, a post specifies that it was changed in 10.04. What is the actual current behavior and how would one facilitate running file-roller with -h with nautilus and pcmanfm?

Comment: Ugh, file-roller -h doesn't appear to do anything. Anyway I'll just do with a script and file-roller -e

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on PC and Lubuntu 13.04 on netbook. The 12.04 does what you want, the 13.04 is different. The safest way to change this is rightclick on the archive -> open with... -> custom command and fill in: file-roller -h %f

Answer (score 0):

file-roller -h doesnt appear to do anything. If it does in fact work that is the expected solution. Otherwise something like this works in a file `ext_folder` on the path:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=`echo $1 | perl -ne'/(.*)\./ && print $1'`
mkdir $dir
file-roller -e $dir $1 &
```