# Click to "Extract here" possible?

Tags: tar, archive, zip, unzip

For my work I constantly need to unzip zip-archives. I know I can right-click and select "Extract here", but since I do this a lot, this is becoming annoying.

Is there a way to set the default action when double clicking a zip (or any other archive) to "Extract here"?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: There is no way to set the double click action to default to "Extract Here".  Double-clicking executes the "Open" action, and it defaults to a package manager for that.  There's no way that I know of to change that default behavior.

Comment: You might have more luck making a keyboard shortcut to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's much easier in 18.04! (I'm not sure since when this works)

In "Open With" set the application "Files" as default and that's it.

[image: screenshot]

Now when you right-click on the archive, "Extract Here" is the first entry in the context-menu and will be called on doubleclick.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Awesome, this was the comment I hoped for!

Comment: Ingenious. This should be the default out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible on Linux!

Select a `*.zip` file with a right mouse click and go to properties. Instead of using a mouse, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In the textbox, write `file-roller -h` <sup>1</sup>. Select *Add to list*. In case you don't have it installed, use `sudo apt install file-roller -y`.

[image]

Then select `file-roller` and *Set as default*.

[image]

Now, `file-roller` is set as default. You can close the properties window. Now when you open a `zip`, it will be automatically decompressed for you. To do the same for `*.tar.gz` files (`application/x-compressed-tar` in general), skip adding `file-roller` to list as it's already there - only set as default.

Why does it work? Read the manual (`man file-roller`):

```
SYNOPSIS
   file-roller [OPTIONS...]  [FILE...]
OPTIONS
   -f, --extract
          Extract archives asking the destination folder and quit the program

   -h, --extract-here
          Extract archives using the archive name as destination folder and quit the program
```

<sup>1</sup> Some people prefer `file-roller -f` instead of `-h` to choose the destination folder.

See also [Archive manager that extracts into new folder named after archive](https://askubuntu.com/a/371095/639188)